# I am having isssue running Flutter, Have tried different things, but there is reasonable thing on the network

Tags: flutter, exception, gradle, mobile, command

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QyXK.png)AM new to flutter, i learnt that the way to run a flutter code is be using "flutter run",
Anytime i run my flutter app, it does nothing.

Special thanks for whom help me out

have tried running it on different project that normally works before, but now it not working

Comment: We would need more information like a stack trace, a screenshot of your terminal after running flutter run, the IDE you are using. That would help us to answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in code ,you write flutter run inside the appbar which is not correct. so just remove that and everything works fine.